# While loop not working as intended - input

Tags: python

```
printType = (int(input('Please select your print type. (1 or 2.): ')))
if (printType != 1) or (printType != 2):
    while (printType != 1) or (printType != 2):
        print('Invalid input. Please select 1 or 2.')
        printType = (int(input("1 or 2?: ")))
```

whenever i run this block, it just keeps on looping regardless of if i put 1 or 2 in. im completely lost and dont know whats going wrong here. any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `or` should be `and`.

Comment: There's no need for the `if` statement, since `while` tests the condition the first time by itself.

Comment: @Barmar: Although it's much more clearly written as `printType not in (1, 2):`

Comment: @ShadowRanger Of course. But I'm just pointing out the logical error. Alternate formations are in the linked question.

Comment: `(printType != 1) or (printType != 2)` this condition will ALWAYS be true.  if printType is 1, then `printType != 2` will be true, and likewise if printType is 2, then `printType != 1` will be true.  No matter what value printType has, this condition is true.